# Python - Mouse clicks/Keyboard Clicks on window in background

Tags: python-3.x, automation, bots

I wanted to create a metin2 bot, nothing complicated. I am new into that so i just started to look for tutorials on youtube to find something that would lead me to world of coding, how does it work, what language is used to write it ect. So I found a tutorial on youtube about open CV [Learn Code By Gaming - OpenCV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KecMlLUuiE4&t=112s) and thought that's awesome thing to start with.

I got to the point where I can easily detect the names of monsters/metins and wont have any problems in finding the right points to click. After detection started working I thought about automating clicking on the window to farm some items etc. Simple things like clicking e.g 50 pixels below the name to auto attack worked just fine but the problem was that I wanted to make more bots to maximalize farming. So when i started to add more clients I got a problem where e.g you have to hold down SPACE in one window to attack from horse and click on another window which was stopping attacking from horse. So I thought about finding some code that can basically send message directly to window without controlling a mouse or keyboard so you can run multiple bots in one time and each will do perfect meanwhile you can do anything else on pc because your mouse and keyboard aren't used.

Let's start from code I found and none worked for windows in background (even with administrator privileges). Pyautogui doesn't work in background (window has to be in foreground to be clicked on and it controls mouse so there is no point in using that.

From that code I learned that I need to find "window ID" to connect to it and send messages. When i print hWnd it shows the numbers in Terminal and code passes without any fails but does nothing except printing the window ID ( Parent Handle ).  Ofc I pip installed pywin32

```
import win32gui
import win32api
import win32con

def click(x, y):

hWnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Client")
print(hWnd)
lParam = win32api.MAKELONG(x, y)

win32api.SendMessage(hWnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, lParam)
win32api.SendMessage(hWnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, lParam) 
click(100, 100)
```

Than i found another code that looked similar but used different function so first i used

```
wdname = 'Client'

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, wdname) # parent handle
print(hwnd)
```

Which printed me a window ID that i used in parameters in function

```
def control_click(x, y, handle, button):

l_param = win32api.MAKELONG(x, y)

if button == 'left':
    win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, l_param)
    win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, l_param)

elif button == 'right':
    win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_RBUTTONDOWN, 0, l_param)
    win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_RBUTTONUP, 0, l_param)

control_click(200, 200, 329570, button ='left')
```

But it still did nothing but code passed clear

Anyone have any ideas about how to make clicks/keyboard clicks in python on window in background without taking controll of mouse/keyboard? If you have any experience in automating and know better ways to create automation for clicking ect. and want to share it please do. If that can be done in another programming language also share your toughts about that of course if you want to.

Windows 10 x64
Python used: 3.9.2

All codes i found in topics were out of date that s why i am asking for help there. Thanks in advance :)